# Table with Multicolumn Header (in Beamer)

Tags: tables, beamer

When I use multicolumn for a table, the heading for the merged columns occupy only one column instead of the total number of merged columns. Is there a way to sort this? Here is a MWE -

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\tiny}
\usepackage{color} 

\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\title{my slides}
\author{}
\date{5/2/2022}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begingroup
\scriptsize

\begin{frame}
    
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Sample Resistance data from $ 1mg/ml $ of CNT solution}
  \resizebox{!}{.4\paperheight}{
    \begin{tabularx}{1.15\textwidth}{CCCCCCCC}
        \toprule
          &       & \multicolumn{3}{C}{Sample on cellulose filter} & \multicolumn{3}{C}{Sample on Wafer} \\
          %\midrule
    Sample  & Thickness ($ \mu m $) & Resistance ($\Omega$) & Sheet resistance ($ \Omega $) & Resistivity ($ \Omega\: cm $) & Resistance ($ \Omega $) & Sheet resistance ($ \Omega $) & Resistivity ($ \Omega\: cm $) \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}[0]{*}{10 ml} & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{7.07} & 8.42037 & 38.14444 & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{0.033292836} & 11.16161 & 50.5659 & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{0.035330583} \\
          &       & 9.03046 & 40.90815 &       & 11.08799 & 50.22873 &  \\
          &       & 8.73346 & 39.56346 &       & 10.84388 & 49.12298 &  \\
    Average &       & 8.728096667 & 39.53868333 &       & 11.03116 & 49.97253667 &  \\
          \midrule
    \multirow{6}[0]{*}{20 ml} & \multirow{7}[0]{*}{12.905} & 8.69023 & 39.36688 & \multirow{7}[0]{*}{0.034299208} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{5.62617} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{25.48672} & \multirow{7}[0]{*}{0.032975463} \\
          &       & 8.62305 & 39.06262 &       &       &       &  \\
          &       & 8.46726 & 38.3569 &       & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{5.70038} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{25.82339} &  \\
          &       & 8.69199 & 39.37495 &       &       &       &  \\
          &       & 8.89965 & 40.31551 &       & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{5.59538} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{25.3473} &  \\
          &       & 8.90406 & 40.33552 &       &       &       &  \\
    Average &       & 8.712706667 & 39.46873 &       & 8.593513333 & 25.55247 &  \\
    \midrule
          &       &       &       & \multirow{5}[0]{*}{0.01052849} &       &       &  \\
    \multirow{3}[0]{*}{30 ml} & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{25.005} & 5.11619 & 21.81757 &       & 2.93069 & 13.27621 & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{0.032756433} \\
          &       & 4.59474 & 20.80073 &       & 2.79338 & 12.65416 &  \\
          &       & 4.76615 & 21.59088 &       & 2.95128 & 13.36949 &  \\
    Average &       & 4.825693333 & 21.40306 &       & 2.891783333 & 13.09995333 &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
}
  \label{table1}%
\end{table}%

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Sample Resistance data from $ 0.5mg/ml $ of CNT solution}
 \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabularx}{1.63\textwidth}{*{11}{C}}
        \toprule
           & \multicolumn{4}{C}{
                At the wafer} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{After baking at 400C in glovebox} & \multicolumn{4}{C}{On cellulose filter}\\
    Sample  & Resistance ($\Omega$) & Sheet resistance ($\Omega$) & Thickness ($ \mu m $) & Resistivity ($ \Omega \: cm $) & Sheet resistance ($\Omega$) & Resistivity ($ \Omega\:cm $) & Resistance ($\Omega$) & Sheet resistance ($\Omega$) & Thickness ($ \mu m $) & Resistivity ($ \Omega\: cm $) \\
    \midrule
    10 ml & 8.6347 & 39.1154 & 11.3  & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{0.045361063} & 32    & \multirow{5}[0]{*}{0.0387} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{16.55097} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{74.97601} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{11.3} & \multirow{10}[0]{*}{0.083748478} \\
          & 8.8625 & 40.1469 & 10.5  &       & 34    &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & 8.7009 & 39.4149 & 12.6  &       & 34    &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Average & 8.7327 & 39.55906667 & 11.46666667 &       & 35    &       & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{16.04057} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{72.663889} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{10.5} &  \\
          &       &       &       & Average & 33.75 &       &       &       &       &  \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & 26.2074 & 118.7196 & 3.2   & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{0.058517203} &       &       & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{15.77689} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{71.46949} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{12.6} &  \\
          & 23.751 & 107.5919 & 4.1   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & 25.6407 & 116.1524 & 4.1   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Average & 15.78998571 & 71.52859524 & 8.180952381 &       &       &       & 16.12281 & 73.036463 & 11.46666667 &  \\
          
    \midrule
    20 ml & 13.1859 & 59.732 & 7.2   & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{0.043931432} & 42    & \multirow{5}[0]{*}{0.032745} & 7.62057 & 34.52141 & 7.2   & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{0.024851521} \\
          & 13.2219 & 59.8952 & 7.5   &       & 45    &       & 7.35304 & 33.29376 & 7.5   &  \\
          & 12.908 & 58.4732 & 7.5   &       & 46    &       & 7.27021 & 32.93424 & 7.5   &  \\
    Average & 13.10526667 & 59.3668 & 7.4   &       & 44    &       & 7.414606667 & 33.58313667 & 7.4   &  \\
          &       &       &       & Average & 44.25 &       &       &       &       &  \\
          \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
}
  \label{table2}%
\end{table}%

\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\multicolumn{3}{c}`instead of `\multicolumn{3}{C}` should result in the desired output.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Dou you really need all those packages loaded in preamble. Some of them are loaded twice with different options. BTW, beamer load some packages itself, for example `amsmath`,  etc.

Comment: @Zarko I don't really need them, I was just reusing different tex files from 2-3 years back and added stuff as I needed it without thinking of duplicate package loading lol.

Comment: @leandriis Much appreciate your help. That did the job.

Comment: You should bear in mind, that presentation is not article or report, so for it are different rules. For example, for `multicolum` has beamer own mechanism, the same is for lists (`enumitem`  not collaborate well with beamer) etc.  Anyway, all is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In MWE below are consider only packages relevant to writing table.
- For table are added `tabularray` and `siunitx` package (loaded by `\UseTblrLibrary`). Using them table and can nicely fit in frame without using `\resizebox` box. Consequently can be prescribed font size `footnotesize`
- I suggest to round number so that in each column has the same decimal digits (by tis table become more consistent)
- MWE, which consider only the first table, the second you can edited /for exercise/ on the same way yourself):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\tiny}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \footnotesize
\caption{Sample Resistance data from \qty{1}{\milli\gram\per\milli\litre} of CNT solution}
    \sisetup{round-mode=places,
             round-precision=5}
\label{table1}
    \begin{tblr}{ colsep = 2pt,
                 colspec = {@{} Q[l, si={table-format=2,
                                         round-precision=0}]
                                X[c,m, si={table-format=2.3,
                                           round-precision=3}]
                           *{2}{X[c,m, si={table-format=2.5}]}
                                X[c,m, si={table-format=1.5}]
                           *{2}{X[c,m, si={table-format=2.5}]}
                                X[c,m, si={table-format=1.5}]
                           @{}},
                 rowsep=1pt
                 }
    \toprule
    &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{Sample on cellulose filter}}}
            &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{Sample on Wafer}}}  \\
    \cmidrule[r]{3-5}\cmidrule[l]{6-8}
{{{Sample}}}
    & {{{Thickness (\unit{\micro\metre})}}}
        & {{{Resistance (\unit{\ohm})}}}
            & {{{Sheet resistance (\unit{\ohm})}}}
                & {{{Resistivity (\unit{\ohm\centi\metre})}}}
                    & {{{Resistance (\unit{\ohm})}}}
                        & {{{Sheet resistance (\unit{\ohm})}}}
                            & {{{Resistivity (\unit{\ohm\centi\metre})}}} \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=3]{l} \qty{10}{\milli\litre}
    & \SetCell[r=4]{l} 7.07
        & 8.42037
            & 38.14444
                & \SetCell[r=4]{c} 0.033292836
                    & \SetCell[r=4]{c} 11.16161
                        & 50.5659
                            &  \SetCell[r=4]{c} 0.035330583 \\
    &   & 9.03046
            & 40.90815
                &   & 11.08799
                        & 50.22873
                            &                               \\
    &   & 8.73346
            & 39.56346
                &   & 10.84388
                        & 49.12298
                            &                               \\
{{{Average}}}
    &   & 8.728096667
            & 39.53868333
                &   & 11.03116
                        & 49.97253667
                            &                               \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=6]{l} \qty{20}{\milli\litre}
    &\SetCell[r=7]{l} 12.905
        & 8.69023 
            & 39.36688 
                & \SetCell[r=7]{l} 0.034299208
                    & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 5.62617
                        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 25.48672
                            & \SetCell[r=7]{l} 0.032975463  \\
    &   & 8.62305 
            & 39.06262 
                &   &   &   &  \\
    &   & 8.46726 
            & 38.3569 
                &   & \SetCell[r=2]{l}  5.70038
                        & \SetCell[r=2]{l}  25.82339
                            &  \\
    &   & 8.69199 
            & 39.37495 
                &   &   &   &  \\
    &   & 8.89965 
            & 40.31551 
                &   & \SetCell[r=2]{l}  5.59538
                        & \SetCell[r=2]{l}  25.3473
                            &  \\
    &   & 8.90406 
            & 40.33552 
                &   &   &   &  \\
{{{Average}}} 
    &   & 8.712706667 
            & 39.46873 
                &   & 8.593513333 
                        & 25.55247 
                            &                               \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=3]{l} \qty{30}{\milli\litre}
    & \SetCell[r=4]{c} 25.005
        & 5.11619 
            & 21.81757 
                & \SetCell[r=4]{c} 0.01052849
                    & 2.93069 
                        & 13.27621 
                            & \SetCell[r=4]{c} 0.032756433  \\
    &   & 4.59474 
            & 20.80073 
                &   & 2.79338 
                        & 12.65416 
                            &                               \\
    &   & 4.76615 
            & 21.59088 
                &   & 2.95128 
                        & 13.36949 
                            &                               \\
{{{Average}}} 
    &   & 4.825693333 
            & 21.40306 
                &   & 2.891783333 
                        & 13.09995333 
                            &                               \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get this error on compiling your MWE - File `tabularray.sty' not found \UseTblrLibrary latex. Your formatting of the table looks very nice and hence the upvote.

Comment: @AniruddhaGhosh, how/where you compile my MWE? You must check if `tabularray` is installed. I tested MWE with `tabularray` version 2022A.

Comment: I tested it in TeXstudio 3.1.2 (git 3.1.2) Using Qt Version 5.15.2, compiled with Qt 5.15.2 R.

Comment: @AniruddhaGhosh, huh, this complete unknown to me (except editor, which is not important). I use MiKTeX, recent version and at first time load `tabularray`  manually. For editor I use WinEdt,. I thought you might be using Overleaf, which has a relatively old version of `tabularray` installed, (2021L). Sorry, about installtion of missing packages I can't help you,

Comment: I use MacTex 2021 on a macbook pro.